# android layout according to language selected

Tags: android, layout

I would like to know if there is any good idea how to switch layouts according to application language selected - e.g. switch between left-to-right layout and right-to-left layout. Have different images or written text and ofcourse the position.

I thought doing it using a private member in the application that indicates the current language selected. According to this parameter I can choose the related XML and text etc.
Actualy I might create some LayoutFactory class, although I don't really think it is required.

But will have to create the realted layout XMLs.
Is there any option to put subdirectories under he layout?
Or should I name the files like en_***.xml and he_***.xml etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `values` and `drawable` you can add folders like `values-fr` for French or `values-ja` for Japanese. The `-fr` indicates that if your phone is set to French localization the app will use any folder that has the `-fr` added to its name. I'm guessing this goes for the `layout` folder aswell.

You can read about [Localization here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html) .